# I have a component that triggers the onClick event on render after the initial onClick

Tags: reactjs, graphql, material-ui, event-handling, react-apollo

```
const component = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [getUserByEmail, { data, error, loading }] = useLazyQuery(userQuery,
    {
      variables: {
        userEmail: email,
      },
    });

    const handleClick = () => {
       getUserByEmail(email)
    }

    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} className={props.classes.emailFormContainer}>
        <TextField
          className={props.classes.emailFieldContainer}
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button
          className={props.classes.button}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Join Now
        </Button>
      </Grid>
}
```

I'm having an issue where, after the initial query or button click and not before, the onClick event for the button fires each time I begin to type in the textfield. Would anyone know why this is happening? I'm using graphql and apollo for my queries and material ui for my components.

Comment: hmmm, initial query with lazy? ... move `variables` from `useLazyQuery` into `getUserByEmail( { variables: userEmail: email ...`

Comment: Awesome, thanks man but why did that work?

Comment: thats the proper way to do this ... read docs, search for tutorials?